# Hashcat Errors and Line Length Exception

Tags: hash, hashcat

I have a hash i am trying to crack. I placed this hash as is inside a file called passwordhash.hash

```
*27D47D48F5C4982E785A7BB31D471DF945395AAD
```

I run this command:

```
hashcat -m 300 -a ~/Documents/passwordhash.hash ~/Documents/rockyou.txt
```

I get line length exception on each password in the dictionary like so:

```
WARNING: Hashfile 'rockyou.txt' on line 178975 (tillman1): Line-length exception
WARNING: Hashfile 'rockyou.txt' on line 178976 (tikka): Line-length exception
WARNING: Hashfile 'rockyou.txt' on line 178977 (tiki): Line-length exception
```

I ran the hash using john and hash-identifier, they both identify the hash to be mysql.

```
Possible Hashs:
[+]  MySQL 160bit - SHA-1(SHA-1($pass

Loaded 1 password hash (mysql-sha1, MySQL 4.1+ [SHA1 128/128 AVX 4x])
```

What am i doing wrong here? i read elsewhere the Line-length exception has something to do with the mode.

After adding -a 0 i get

```
ERROR: clGetDeviceIDs() : - 1 : CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a number after the `-a` to specify the attack mode. Maybe that's the problem? Instead it should be:

`hashcat -m 300 -a 0 ~/Documents/passwordhash.hash ~/Documents/rockyou.txt`

[This page from the FAQ](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#line-length_exception_wait_what) might also be helpful. It addresses other common line-length error causes.

Comment: i add the 0 but now i get a new error message. ERROR: clGetDeviceIDs() : - 1 : CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Does cracking the example hashes work for you? I want to make sure it's a problem with the command rather than missing a library or something.

Comment: I tried he example hashes from the hashcat website, but i still get that CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND Error.

Comment: Yup, so it sounds like it's an issue with your installation rather than with the hashcat problem itself. Try googling the error and seeing if you can fix it, or maybe try running a VM and install hashcat inside that instead.